# Filter all words with the same character length except some specific words

Tags: r, filter, grepl

I know I can remove all word items that have just 2 characters with the following order:

data %>% filter(str_length(word) != 2)

In my Case I would like to filter all items with 2 characters but some specific words like "EU" should be still in the tibble. Is it possible to define some expections to the order above?

Comment: Does this work? `data %>% filter(str_length(word) != 2 || word == "EU")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to filter all two-letters word except "EU" and "UE":

```
test <- tibble(word=c("Word", "Another word", "Wo", "Wa", "EU","UE"))

test

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  word        
  <chr>       
1 Word        
2 Another word
3 Wo          
4 Wa          
5 EU          
6 UE   

test %>% filter(ifelse(str_length(word)==2 & !grepl("EU|UE", word), FALSE, TRUE))

 A tibble: 4 x 1
  word        
  <chr>       
1 Word        
2 Another word
3 EU          
4 UE
```